# opencv Mat_.at<_tp>. What does it mean?

Tags: opencv, k-means

I am unable to understand what does `.at<_tp>` mean in openCV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[at](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#cv-mat-at) is a method of the [Mat](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat) class which returns a reference to the specified element. The argument inside the angle brackets is the element type of the matrix.

e.g. to set the element at position (1,2) in a matrix `H` of type `int` to `3`, you'd do:

```
H.at<int>(1,2)=3;
```